# printf() and float error

Tags: c, casting, double, printf

```
int number1 = 23;
int number2 = 100;

printf("Output: %.2d", double(number1) / number2);
```

This I want:

```
Output: 0.23
```

This I get:

```
error: expected expression before ‘double’
```

I don't understand the error message. How to do cast the integer to double and perform the calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are typecasting the wrong way, also the format specifier is incorrect:

```
printf("Output: %.2f", (double)number1 / number2);
```

Here is the Output:

http://ideone.com/10a1Ka

Comment: Thanks! Stupid me for not seeing I typecasted it the wrong way.

Comment: That's ok - we all make such mistakes occasionally :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use`%f` format specifier

```
   printf("Output: %.2f", (double) number1 / number2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax of cast is `(double)number1 / number2`, and you should use `%.2f` as the format specifier.

```
printf("Output: %.2f", (double)number1 / number2);
//                 ^   ^      ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors.

Firstly you are casting incorrectly. Cast to double like this:

```
(double)number1
```

Secondly you used the wrong print format specifier. You used `d` which is for integers. Use `f` instead. Putting it all together gives:

```
printf("Output: %.2f", (double)number1 / number2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look at some basics of format specifiers shall we?

```
**Format specifier**    **Characters matched**  **Argument type**

%c                           any single character   char

%d, %i                       integer            integer type

%u                           integer            unsigned

%o                           octal integer      unsigned

%x, %X                       hex integer        unsigned

%e, %E,%f, %g, %G            floating point 
                             number             floating type

%p                           address format     void *


%s                           any sequence of 
                             non-whitespace 
                             characters         char
```

You used "%d" instead of "%f" there is no way the compiler is gonna print a floating point value.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. I tried with both the &f and &d, I thought d stood for double. But the problem was mainly in the syntax of the casting. This is my very first C program.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow xD

Comment: Subtle detail on `%c`: The "Argument type" is `int`.  "... the int argument is converted to an unsigned char, and the resulting character is written." C11 7.21.6.1 8.

Comment: The "Argument type" for `%s` is not `char`.  More like `char *`. ("pointer to the initial element of an array of character type").  "Characters matched" & "any sequence of non-whitespace characters" sounds like you are referring to `scanf()` and not `printf()`.